# Sendmail Attachment Issue in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, sendmail

I have a sendmail program in vb.net.  I have attachments sending just fine.  The problem is when there is NO ATTACHMENT, the program errors out.  How do i handle no attachment to bypass and send with no attachment?  The below works fine.

Yea yea i know, my naming convention is horrible.  I will change once i have the logic 100% complete.

```
Imports System.Net.Mail
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        If TextBox1.Text = "" Then
            MsgBox("Please describe the issue you're having Bender, I'm not a mindreader!")
            Exit Sub
        Else
            lblpleasewait.Visible = True
            Delay(2000)
            Dim Recipients As New List(Of String)
            Recipients.Add("emtnap6@yahoo.com")
            Dim FromEmailAddress As String = Recipients(0)
            Dim Subject As String = "IT Help!"
            Dim Body As String = TextBox1.Text
            Dim UserName As String = "fakeout"
            Dim Password As String = "fakeout"
            Dim Port As Integer = 587
            Dim Server As String = "smtp.gmail.com"
            Dim Attachments As New List(Of String)
            MsgBox(SendEmail(Recipients, FromEmailAddress, Subject, Body, UserName, Password, Server, Port, Attachments))
            TextBox2.Text = "Attach Screenshot:"
            TextBox2.TextAlign = HorizontalAlignment.Right
            lblpleasewait.Visible = False
            TextBox1.Text = ""
            TextBox1.Focus()
        End If
    End Sub
    Sub delay(ByVal delay_ms As Integer)
        Dim tspan As New TimeSpan
        Dim tstart = Now
        While tspan.TotalMilliseconds < delay_ms
            tspan = Now - tstart
            Application.DoEvents()
        End While
    End Sub


    Function SendEmail(ByVal Recipients As List(Of String), _
                      ByVal FromAddress As String, _
                      ByVal Subject As String, _
                      ByVal Body As String, _
                      ByVal UserName As String, _
                      ByVal Password As String, _
                      Optional ByVal Server As String = "smtp.gmail.com", _
                      Optional ByVal Port As Integer = 587, _
                      Optional ByVal Attachments As List(Of String) = Nothing) As String
        Dim Email As New MailMessage()
        Try
            Dim SMTPServer As New SmtpClient
            ''For Each Attachment As String In Attachments
            ''    Email.Attachments.Add(New Attachment(Attachment))
            'Next
            Dim mailattach As String = TextBox2.Text
            Dim attachment As System.Net.Mail.Attachment
            attachment = New System.Net.Mail.Attachment(mailattach)
            Email.Attachments.Add(attachment)

            Email.From = New MailAddress(FromAddress)
            For Each Recipient As String In Recipients
                Email.Bcc.Add(Recipient)
            Next
            Email.Subject = Subject
            Email.Body = Body
            SMTPServer.Host = Server
            SMTPServer.Port = Port
            SMTPServer.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential(UserName, Password)
            SMTPServer.EnableSsl = True
            SMTPServer.Send(Email)
            Email.Dispose()
            Return "Email to Derek was successfully sent."
        Catch ex As SmtpException
            Email.Dispose()
            Return "Sending Email Failed. Smtp Error."
        Catch ex As ArgumentOutOfRangeException
            Email.Dispose()
            Return "Sending Email Failed. Check Port Number."
        Catch Ex As InvalidOperationException
            Email.Dispose()
            Return "Sending Email Failed. Check Port Number."
        End Try
    End Function

    Private Sub FolderBrowserDialog1_HelpRequest(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        If (FolderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog() = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK) Then
            TextBox2.Text = FolderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        OpenFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop)
        If (OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog() = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK) Then
            TextBox2.Text = OpenFileDialog1.FileName
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        TextBox1.Focus()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
        If Not Environment.Is64BitProcess Then
            Process.Start("C:\Windows\sysnative\SnippingTool.exe")
        Else
            Process.Start("C:\Windows\system32\SnippingTool.exe")
        End If

    End Sub

    Private Sub OpenFileDialog1_FileOk(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs) Handles OpenFileDialog1.FileOk
        OpenFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = Environment.SpecialFolder.MyComputer
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Also, show the rest of the code...  just the mail portion.

Comment: What condition determines this... that would be a start.

Comment: If your doing a list according to your other issue you had, loop through the list, if nothing is there skip adding the attachment.

Comment: Mr CoDeXeR all it is is a fileopen button that puts the file path chosen to a textbox and then the above event happens.  How would i loop through the function and if nothing there, skip it?  If you need i can post the rest of my code.

Comment: Post rest of your code please.

Comment: Error is "File Not Found"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should solve the problem.

```
If TextBox2.text <> "" then
    Dim mailattach As String = TextBox2.Text
    Dim attachment As System.Net.Mail.Attachment
    attachment = New System.Net.Mail.Attachment(mailattach)
    Email.Attachments.Add(attachment)
End if
```

Comment: You're very welcome.
Since my answer helped you, please Mark it as Answer and also up vote it.